# How to select jquery tab through hash

Tags: jquery

I am pretty new to jQuery. I wonder how I can select a jQuery tab after the user submits his settings through PHP.
The url is like `instellingen#1`.
When I submit the info then it reloads the page and goes always to `instellingen#0`.

The code at this moment:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#instellingen").tabs({
        selected: (location.hash != "") ? location.hash.replace("#", "") : 0,
        show: function (event, ui) {
            location.hash = $(this).tabs("option", "selected");

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you Can simple do your code like this:

you will need to use:  window.location.hash;

```
if (window.location.hash != '') {
window.location.hash = "put what you want";
// Do your staff
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alok. However it doesnt work. This is what i have know:
    $("#instellingen").tabs({
    if (window.location.hash != '') {
     window.location.hash = "instellingen#3";
    } else {
     selected: (location.hash != "") ? location.hash.replace("#", "") : 0,
     location.hash = $(this).tabs("option", "selected");
    }
   });